# LinkLabel border color

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using `LinkLabel`, and want to set the border to color red.
I set the `BorderStyle` to `FixedSingle`
and the `ForeColor` to red but only the text is red, the border is still black.

If i do the same for `Label` control, I get the border and the text as red, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `BorderStyle` to `None` and draw your own.

```
private void linkLabel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (linkLabel1.ForeColor == Color.Red)
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, linkLabel1.DisplayRectangle, linkLabel1.ForeColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    else
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, linkLabel1.DisplayRectangle, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LinkLabels don't really have a border color property but you could hook into the OnPaint event and draw your own border.  There's code showing how to do that at [windows-tech.info](http://www.windows-tech.info/3/7e4d3cb98a7b2b1b.php).

As they mention there you could derive a new control from the LinkLabel control if you plan to re-use it. At that point you could even add a "CustomBorderColor" property and use that. An unset color comes up as Empty, so I'd go with something that has a default of transparent. Like this:

```
using System.Drawing.Color;
private Color m_CustomBorderColor = Color.Transparent;

public Color CustomBorderColor
{
    get { return m_CustomBorderColor; }
    set { m_CustomBorderColor = value; }
}
```